# django rest ImportError

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

as you see in provided image i have app named academy in the academy folder i have middleware folder. in one of my mcustom middleware file i want work with a model (manager model you can see in image)

in my custom middleware when i import model like this:
`from academy.api.v1.manager.models import UserViewControll`

i get this error :

```
    from academy.api.v1.manager.models import UserViewControll
ImportError: No module named 'academy.api'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
...
```

why?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `api` folder is in the outer project directory (the one that contains `manage.py`), then you don't need to include `academy` in the import. Change it to:

```
from api.v1.manager.models import UserViewControll
```

Comment: api is the folder that my apps are in v1 folder api dont have manage.py

structure is api->v1->theapps

Comment: if i delete "academy" ide say unresolved refrence with error

Comment: If you get an unresolved reference error then that's an issue with how you have configured your project in the IDE, not a problem with the code itself. I still don't understand where `manage.py` is from your comments and screenshots, but my answer assumes it's in `ac/academy`.